# Finding build output in Visual Studio 6 (visual basic)

Tags: vb6

I realize this is going to be an exotic question, but I just can't find the answer.

I'm trying to fix up and enhance an old visual basic-based application.

My problem is: where is the output directory with the compiled binaries?

Thanks.

If some clarification is needed, please ask.

Comment: Hard to know if you are asking where a GUI IDE compile places compiled binaries or how to specify a path on a command line compile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the .VBP, if there is a line specifying the path like this

```
Path32="C:\"
```

Then the resulting EXE will be built at that location. Otherwise, it will be built in the same directory as the .VBP file. The path can be relational as well and may not be a fully qualified path.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want the `/outdir` switch.  This overrides the `Path32` setting in the Project file.

```
VB6[.EXE]  [[{/run | /r}] | [/runexit] | [{/make | /m}] projectname]
           [/out filename] [/outdir path] [/d const=value{[:constN=valueN]}]
           [/mdi | /sdi] [{/cmd argument | /c argument}]

Options:

/run or /r projectname  Tells Visual Basic to compile projectname and run it,
                        using the arguments stored in the Command Line
                        Arguments field of the Make tab of the Project
                        Properties dialog box.

/runexit projectname    Tells Visual Basic to compile projectname and run it.
                        Visual Basic will exit when the project returns to
                        design mode.

/make or /m projectname Tells Visual Basic to compile projectname and make an
                        executable file from it, using the existing settings
                        stored in the project file.

/out filename           Specifies a file to receive errors when you build using
                        /m or /runexit. If you do not use /out, command line
                        bild errors are displayed in a message box.

/outdir path            Specifies a directory path to place all output files in
                        when using /make.  This path must already exist.

/d or /D const=value... Tells Visual Basic which values to use for conditional
                        compilation constants when making an .EXE or ActiveX
                        component with the /make switch.  Separate multiple
                        constants with colons.

/cmd or /c argument     Specifies a command string to be passed to the Command$
                        function. When used, it must be the last switch on the
                        command line.

/mdi or /sdi            Changes the Visual Basic environment to either Single
                        Document Interface (SDI) or Multiple Document Interface
                        (MDI) mode.  Visual Basic remains in this mode until
                        you change it.

/?                      Displays a list of valid command line switches.

You may use a group name in place of projectname in any of the above switches.
```

Works fine here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent 'bin/lib' output directory for VB6.  When you compile a VB6 project, the default is to compile to the same folder as the project (vbp file).  It is also possible to compile to any other folder available to the user.

Comment: Also note that any intermediary (obj) files are deleted at the end of the compile.